# Stack Exchange sites and url paths

Tags: support, stack-exchange, hyperlinks, redirection

Here's how a url of a post looks:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166063/microsoft-access-database-instad-of-sqlite-or-local-database`

What exactly is happening behind when I try to visit the following url:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166063/some-text-here`

?

I mean, does it make a Permanent Redirect from that url (containing `some-text-here`) to the original one? Or it just focuses on the `id` and throws everything after the `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the http traffic when you make a request to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166063/some-text-here`, the core engine extracts the id, and redirects you to the true url if necessary.  So you'll see a `Status Code:301 Moved Permanently` and the response header will include `Location:/questions/6166063/microsoft-access-database-instead-of-sqlite-or-local-database`.